# Sorting an array of JSON by Time

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, sorting

I get the following JSON array as response from server.
Now how do I sort this JSON array by appointmentStart?

```
  appointments = [
  {
appointmentEnd: "2014-04-09T09:30:00+02:00"
appointmentNote: "Peter - 09/04 - 8 AM"
appointmentStart: "2014-04-09T08:00:00+02:00"
appointmentStatus: "auto-approved"
},
  {
appointmentEnd: "2014-04-09T14:00:00+02:00"
appointmentNote: "Peter - 09/04 - 12:30"
appointmentStart: "2014-04-09T12:30:00+02:00"
appointmentStatus: "auto-approved"
},
  {
appointmentEnd: "2014-04-09T17:00:00+02:00"
appointmentNote: "Peter - 09/04 - 15:30"
appointmentStart: "2014-04-09T15:30:00+02:00"
appointmentStatus: "auto-approved"
},
  {
appointmentEnd: "2014-04-09T15:30:00+02:00"
appointmentNote: ""
appointmentStart: "2014-04-09T14:00:00+02:00"
appointmentStatus: "auto-approved"
},
  {
appointmentEnd: "2014-04-09T11:00:00+02:00"
appointmentNote: "09:30"
appointmentStart: "2014-04-09T09:30:00+02:00"
appointmentStatus: "auto-approved"
}
  ]
```

**Many thanks in advance for the answer**

Thanks,
Chidan

Comment: Please provide some research efforts, by posting any relevant code you tried!

Comment: `appointments.sort(function(a,b) { return parseFloat(a.appointmentStart) - parseFloat(b.appointmentStart) } );`

Answer (score 0):

I think I found the answer:

```
var x = appointments.sort(function(a,b) {
    return Date.parse(a.appointmentStart) - Date.parse(b.appointmentStart);
});
```